# Max physical memory use of a process

Tags: linux, bash

If I want to estimate the max physical memory use of a process, can I simply iteratively invoke "top" command for that process and pick up the maximum value of "RES" field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but understand that you're measuring properties of the system as much as properties of the process. For example on a system under memory pressure, resident set sizes will be smaller even if the process is going the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU version of `time` allows you to display the max RSS during its lifetime using the `%M` format.

Note that you probably have to invoke it as `/usr/bin/time -f %M command...` so you don't run the shell's builtin `time` command.

On OSX, use `/usr/bin/time -l command...`.